# How to hide API key in public open source project?

Tags: web-services, open-source, api-key

I have the problem that I want to program a program that will have to interact with some 3rd party web service. This service requires for specific actions that the client (my program) authorizes itself by both a username/password combination as well as a token. The username/password is specific to the user of my program and no of a problem here. The token (API key) is a problem.

Suppose I want to make my program open source and put its sources on some public server. Of course I cannot hardcode (or include) the API key. Otherwise I would not only break the contract not to publish it but also any (non-authorized) usage will fall back onto me and my program.

According to my research (e.g. [Open source a project but keep API keys confidential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662221/open-source-a-project-but-keep-api-keys-confidential) or [How to hide the API key in my Electron application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114717/how-to-hide-the-api-key-in-my-electron-application)) I could put a proxy server (closed source) between the 3rd party API and my program. Now I see two big open doors for bad-minded people to attack this scenario:

1. As the source code of the main program is open source, any interaction with the proxy can be literally read from source code. An attacker could fork my main program and use exactly the same calls on the proxy but with compromised data. Same result as with openly available keys: My program will get into trouble for other people's bad actions/programming skills.
2. I could add a username/password to authenticate the program against my proxy. I then offer (free-to-use) registration to the proxy in order to allow my program to be used productively. This adds an additional layer of authentication and complexity but is doable. Anyone really wanting to do bad things will nevertheless be able to obtain a password and use his own fork to access the proxy. I cannot put my own keys/encryption/.... anywhere as the necessary routine to decrypt/imitate these will be publicly visible in the open sourced project.

So now I have simply shifted the problem to detect if the running software is an original one, from the 3rd party to my proxy server. I only have the benefit that I could maybe know which user was the bad guy and ban him but this is all I can do while my token might get revoked by this issue.

I am sorry but I did not find a usable solution in the web to this specific problem. How can I attack this problem (on an abstract level)?